# JavaFX ImageView display GIFanimation high GPU

Tags: java, animation, javafx, animated-gif

I am creating JavaFX application and made a loading scene. In this scene i want to show some text like loading or initializing and add some loading spinner animated image as a visual notification that something is loading.

I generate a loading .gif animation created via https://loading.io/ and also downloaded it like frames of animation (multiple .png files).

I noticed that in the JavaFX Scene Builder 8.5.0 when I set the .gif in ImageView, my GPU in Windows task manager went up to 20%, on NVidia GeForce RTX 2070 graphic card and in my opinion this is a problem. I tested with a javafx desktop application, to rule out that is not a problem generated by the scene builder application and got similar results.

The next step that i tried is to create my custom animation using javafx.​animation.Timeline. This is the initializing function that i call from the controller initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) function. This function doesn't use the .gif image, it uses the multiple .png images of the same .gif image as frames.

```
private void initializeAnimation() {
    imgLoading.setCache(true);
    imgLoading.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
    Image[] images = new Image[31];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++){
        images[i] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/es/main/gui/javafx/images/loading/frame-" + i + ".png"));
    }
    Timeline timeLine = new Timeline();
    Collection<KeyFrame> frames = timeLine.getKeyFrames();
    Duration frameGap = Duration.millis(100);
    Duration frameTime = Duration.ZERO;
    for (Image img : images) {
        frameTime = frameTime.add(frameGap);
        frames.add(new KeyFrame(frameTime, e -> imgLoading.setImage(img)));
    }
    timeLine.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeLine.play();
}
```

In the first version i didn't call .setCache() and .setCacheHint() functions, I added them later while testing different variations of the same code. Also i tried  adding

> -Dprism.forceGPU=true -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true -Dprism.order=es2,es1,sw,j2d

as VMOption or some variants that I have read on this forum on improving graphic related settings for java. At the end, after all the changes, results in my task manager didn't change drastically. In the current version i use up to 17% of my GPU on this scene.

When the scene ends, in the next scene with no .gif images or Timeline's my GPU drops to almost 0%.

Running configurations:

> Processor: i9-9900KF
>
> Graphic card: GeForce RTX 2070
>
> Java version "1.8.0_251"
>
> JavaFX version "8.0.251-b08"

Short summary question: How to display animated .gif images correctly in JavaFX without having drastic overhead on the GPU (or CPU when with integrated graphics).

(Edit) 14.09.2020 - Java naming conventions

First thing I didn't noticed that i was not using the same size on my ImageView, so the first thing i changed for testing is adjusting the ImageView the same size as my .gif image (same width and height on both ImageView and .gif image). With this change the GPU percentage lowered to about %5.

As suggested I also upgrading the Java and JavaFX versions:

1. Tried using the jdk 1.8.0_261 with JavaFX built in version 8.0.261-b12 and got similar results.
2. Tried using jdk 14.0.2 with JavaFX version 15+9 (latest openjfx-15) and still got similar results.

Short summary: Upgrading the Java and JavaFX version didn't change anything relating this issue. Using the same size helped, but I think I can improve even better with your help.

Comment: 1. Do you really think it is worthwhile to investigate performance issues on such an outdated version of JavaFX? JavaFX 15 came out just this week. 2. Why don't you provide a small, reproducible example. This would increase your chance that someone is willing to invest some time in analyzing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you'd probably see some performance gains if you used one or more `RotateTransition` rather than key frame animation.

Here's a simple example using multiple transitions in a [ParallelTransition](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/ParallelTransition.html):

```
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (100, 40, 100, 100);
        rect.setArcHeight(50);
        rect.setArcWidth(50);
        rect.setFill(Color.VIOLET);
    
        RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(3000));
        rt.setByAngle(180);
        rt.setAutoReverse(true);
    
        FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000));
        ft.setFromValue(1.0);
        ft.setToValue(0.3);
        ft.setCycleCount(4);
        ft.setAutoReverse(true);

        ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition(rect, ft, rt);
        pt.play();            

        root.getChildren().add(rect);

        stage.show();
    
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a great idea to use one frame of the spinner and rotate it, but it wont look as good as the animation in the link in my post. In this spinner if you analyze images frame by frame, you will notice that it doesn't only rotate it also changes colors opacity, But this is a great idea for simple spinners.

Comment: If you want to get fancy, you can combine transitions like [FadeTransition](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/FadeTransition.html) and [RotateTransition](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/RotateTransition.html) using a [ParallelTransition](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/ParallelTransition.html).  I edited the answer to suit.

Comment: Will try, but I am not sure why java has problems with gif loading. In the past I had similar problem using swing as gui.